# Accessing image from database using PHP

Tags: php, image, mysqli, blob

I am having problem in accessing image that I have saved as Long BLOB type in my sql table add_deal, the problem that I am facing is that I am unable to access image and display it on my browser. When I run the programme I see a broken page. I have tried placing "header('Content-type: image/jpeg');" above echo which in turn gives an error stating "image cannot be displayed because it contains errors" I have saved my image as:

```
$image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        $name=addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
        $image_size=getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        $deal_type = $_POST['dealtype'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
        $validity = $_POST['validity'];
        $price=$_POST['cost'];

    $qry="INSERT INTO `add_deal`(`dealtype`, `description`, `quantity`, `validity`, `price`, `image`, `name`) VALUES ('$deal_type','$description','$quantity','$validity','$price','$image','$name')";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$qry);
    if(! $result ) {
          die("Query FAILED. " . mysqli_error($db));
        }
    else
    {
        echo "Your Deal has been placed in your Gallery";
        echo "<br/>Go to <a href='dealhome.php'>home</a> page to see whats in your gallery</b>";
    }
```

and accessing it as:

```
    if(! $result ) {
          die("Query FAILED. " . mysqli_error($db));
        }
            else
    {

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        //echo "<table>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    echo $row['image'];

    }
    }
    //echo "</table>";
    }
```

Comment: Actually you are storing tmp_name in db, not an image file. That's why you are getting issue to display image. You need to read that image file and then store to db.

Comment: use $name instead-of $image